# Extend logical partition with unallocated space

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning

I have a logical partition (Drive E) and a 10 gb unallocated space. Now I want to extend drive E with 10 gb unallocated space on my hard drive. I'm using Minitool Partition Wizard. but when I click extend on drive E, (in minitool) I can't see unallocated space on the options. i can see only primary partitions.

please take a look at the images:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to extend E: into unallocated space that is not adjacent to the partition, without doing odd things that are possible , but not practical (like spanning with dynamic).
 You have 2 other partitions that will have to be "moved" to the ends first. There is partition software that could move the other partitions, then you could expand into the adjacent unallocated space.

Even using such software to move the partitions, that activity , especially with the different file systems, should be done only after you have a backup of all data on that whole drive.

The graphic view of the disk layout in the disk manager, would be handy to see here. In windows , with simple disk partitioning you can only have so many logical partitions in the extended spaces.  There are times when very small Unallocated spaces are not visually shown in the grafic view.